# Filter 2d array to keep only rows with lowest value in a particular column per unique id column value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, filtering

I want to filter my 2d array to eliminate duplicate customerName values.  When two or more rows contain the same customerName, the row with the lowest Difference should be retained.

I have an simple array like this.

```
[
    ['customerName' => "John Dunk", 'customerPhone' => 5555555555, 'Difference' => 125.0],
    ['customerName' => "John Dunk", 'customerPhone' => 5555555555, 'Difference' => 192.0],
    ['customerName' => "James Morle", 'customerPhone' => 111111111, 'Difference' => 145.0],
    ['customerName' => "James Morle", 'customerPhone' => 111111111, 'Difference' => 114.0],
]
```

But I want to make that array like this one.

```
[
    ['customerName' => "John Dunk", 'customerPhone' => 5555555555, 'Difference' => 125.0],
    ['customerName' => "James Morle", 'customerPhone' => 111111111, 'Difference' => 114.0],
]
```

If inside of multidimensional array 2 or more rows have the same "customerName", keep only the row with that given customerName AND the smallest "Difference" value (all others should be found in the result array).

Comment: please add your try and select a single language.

Comment: Okay, I added only php. But what do you mean "add your try"? I added my result. I want the result like the second one.

Comment: By "add your try", they mean for you to post the code that you tried, even if it wasn't successful, which at least gives us something to work with

Comment: Okay, I understood but the problem is here. I don't have any code block to show you. I only have that first multidimensional array and want to make the second multidimensional array. I want to know how to make it, want to know the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to sort descending on `Difference` and then extract and re-index on `customerName`.  This will extract the last ones of `customerName` which are the lowest `Difference`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'Difference'), SORT_DESC, $array);
$result = array_column($array, null, 'customerName');
```

If needed to re-index with integers:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

If you wanted the highest `Difference` then `SORT_ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

With a focus on directness/efficiency, you should only need to iterate the array once (not multiple times).  As you iterate, when a new customerName is encountered, declare a reference variable for future comparison/manipulation and push that reference into the result array. If the customerName is encountered again and the Difference value is lower, then update the values in the reference -- this will directly update the values in the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dJ7hq))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['customerName']])) {
        $ref[$row['customerName']] = $row;
        $result[] =& $ref[$row['customerName']];
    } elseif ($ref[$row['customerName']]['Difference'] > $row['Difference']) {
        $ref[$row['customerName']]['customerPhone'] = $row['customerPhone'];
        $ref[$row['customerName']]['Difference'] = $row['Difference'];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```